# How can I get the selected item from List in React?

Tags: reactjs

I want to get the selected item, and I want to know which item is selected or clicked on.

I am displaying a list of users like so:

```
<InfiniteScroll
    initialLoad={false}
    pageStart={0}
    loadMore={this.handleInfiniteOnLoad}
    hasMore={!this.state.loading && this.state.hasMore}
    useWindow={false}>
    <List 
        dataSource={this.state.data}
        renderItem={item => (
            <List.Item key={item}>
            <List.Item.Meta  
                avatar={<Avatar src="https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/ODTLcjxAfvqbxHnVXCYX.png" /> }
                  title={<a href="#">{item}</a>}/>                
            </List.Item>
        )}>
    </List>
</InfiniteScroll>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's pretty easy to do that you just need to add onClick handler to the renderItem section.

```
renderItem = {(item, index) => (
  <List.Item key={item} onClick={() => this.handleClick(index)}>
    <List.Item.Meta
      avatar={
        <Avatar src="https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/ODTLcjxAfvqbxHnVXCYX.png" />
      }
      title={<a href="#">{item}</a>}
    />
  </List.Item>
)}
```

and for the handleClick function the code will be:

```
handleClick = index => {
  const selectedItem = this.state.data[index];
}
```

**SelectedItem** is the one you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

The above solution should work. But just ensure that you are attaching `onClick` event to a DOM element. If it is a custom component then event handlers won't work. So, in this case `List.Item` (I guess that it is a custom component) needs to access `onClick` as a prop and attach this event to its top most DOM element like the follwing:

```
// List.Item

<li onClick={this.props.onClick} />
```