# React map filtering

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, filter

The work where I have the problem is divided into two parts,
the first part is that I have mapped a list of items from a file called **Data.js**, and when the user selects an option a value from that item gets stored into a variable, this is the code :

```
var selectedName;
  const onButtonClick = mode => {
    selectedName(mode);
};



{UsersNames.map(item => (
  <div onClick={onButtonClick.bind(this, item.title)}>
     <h1>{item.id}</h1>
  </div>
 ))}
```

the second part is that I want to filter another list of items by the variable that is already chosen, which is **title** and display the age of that item, this is the code :

```
{Age.filter(age=> age.title.includes({selectedName})).map(item => (
  <div>
     <h1>{item.age}</h1>
  </div>
))}
```

so basically this is the order of work that I want to get :

```
map 1st list -> user chooses an option of the list -> read the value of trait of the selected option -> display the item of another list that has that trait
```

this method doesn't work.

I hope you understood the assignment because it's rather confusing, and I really don't know if this is the right approach to do something like this or not.

Answer (score 0):

You must create the list you want to display with a unique key for each item in the list. So the key will be the identifier to an object from your json data.
Example object :

```
{
  "userId": 1, <--- Unique key
  "name": Bob,
  "age": 13,
}
```

So you'll display items in a list like (object.name...) and pass object.userId as key for every items of your list.
Then you'll be able to retrieve your json object since you used the id as a key and display the age for the item selected.

You can check : https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html for more informations.

EDIT : [How can I get the selected item from List in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56645450/how-can-i-get-the-selected-item-from-list-in-react) check also this.

And this : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-change-list-items-in-reactjs-when-an-item-is-clicked/

Remember, you got the id of the object, so you can query anything and display it after a request.